# Selenium ONLY Runs ChromeDriver in Headless

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, headless, brave

I have a working python script that uses Selenium with Firefox, but in attempting to run the same script just with a chromedriver set to drive Brave, it gives the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/brave.com/brave/brave is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

And debug log:

```
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:38723/session {"capabilities": {"alwaysMatch": {"goog:chromeOptions": {"binary": "/opt/brave.com/brave/brave", "args": [], "extensions": []}, "browserName": "chrome", "platformName": "any"}, "firstMatch": [{}]}, "desiredCapabilities": {"goog:chromeOptions": {"binary": "/opt/brave.com/brave/brave", "args": [], "extensions": []}, "platform": "ANY", "browserName": "chrome", "version": ""}}
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1:38723
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://127.0.0.1:38723 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 500 318
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
```

However, the script does what I want it to do (minus the GUI) if I just add a headless argument:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driverPath = '/home/user/etc'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/opt/brave.com/brave/brave'
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverPath, options=options)
```

So I am wondering how to get the Brave browser's GUI to run as well. My driver and browser versions are correct. The binary path is correct (I think).

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

as I remember Chrome headless was shipped in Chrome59. So after you successfully installed chrome, can you try to launch chrome from the shell command and check if it's correct installed.

```
chrome \
  --headless \                   # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
  https://stackoverflow.com      # URL to open.
```

The chrome binary name may be chrome or google-chrome or other similes.

Comment: I don't have Chrome installed. I am trying to use chromedriver to run the Brave browser. Brave works normally when I run it normally, but the GUI isn't working when I tell selenium to use the brave binary with chromedriver.

Comment: can you add logger config in your code, and see the details

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)